# What is "ideal size" in CSS spec level 3?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I've been consuming quite a bit of CSS educational content recently and sometimes reading the CSS spec. I've come across the concept of "ideal size" a couple of times. I'm not sure whether it's a strictly technical name or a more loose name.

- [CSS Level 3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#auto-box-sizes)
- [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/) (Flexbox related)
- [FreeCodeCamp article by Kevin Powell](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-grid-changes-how-we-can-think-about-structuring-our-content/) (Grid related)

I *think* "ideal size" is something like "the size that an element wants to be most, if not limited in any way". But I'm not sure.

Is there a formal definition for this term? Or could anyone give an approximate definition of it?

Comment: Ideal size of what? font-size? The minimum font size which is accessibly friendly is 12px. Ideally 14px is better. You use rem or em to allow the browser +- buttons to expand size and screen readers to adjust it. You don't use actual px values.

Comment: My question is not about "ideal size" as a figurative concept like in "the ideal color is ..." or "the ideal way to do X is Y". Instead "ideal size" seems to be a literal concept, see the links I added for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically equivalent to `max-content`

```css
div {
  width: max-content;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>

<div>more text here</div>
```

> A box’s “ideal” size in a given axis when given infinite available space. Usually this is the smallest size the box could take in that axis while still **fitting around its contents**, i.e. **minimizing unfilled space while avoiding overflow**.

So we try to have "no overflow" and "no wasted space" but it can be more complex in some cases.